# How to bin x and y axis of a dataframe (index and column header) or of a 2d array (an image)

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I have a 2d array (grayscale image) and I want to bin the x and y axis to see if there are intensity gradients in the images (both horizontally and vertically).  `pandas.cut()` only performs this action on a column, but I need to bin on the two axes themselves.

I am stuck so I have not tried much except `pandas.cut()`:

```
img = cv2.imread('Image.tif', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
roi1 = pd.DataFrame(img[740:870, 730:835]) #ROI = img(y1:y2, x1:x2)
plt.imshow(roi1)
plt.colorbar()
bins = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 105]
roi1['bins'] = pd.cut(roi1[index], bins)
```

Comment: Please define "bin".  Do you want a 2D histogram between channels? Or a 1D histogram of the values in the image? Or reduce the image to fewer pixels in x and y? Or something else?

Comment: The axes are basically coordinates, and I would like to keep that spatial data by binning the x axis into ~20units.  I then will display these 20unit bins as boxplots to determine if that region has higher or lower intensities.  I do not think histograms would preserve this spatial information